# Using default template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

This question is best asked by example. Say I want to declare a `std::priority_queue` with a comparator function. I could do:

```
auto cmp_fn = [](const std::string& left, const std::string& right) {
    return right < left;
};

std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>, decltype(cmp_fn)> queue(cmp_fn);
```

Is there any way to avoid specifying the middle template parameter so that the default is used? Something like

```
auto cmp_fn = [](const std::string& left, const std::string& right) {
    return right < left;
};

std::priority_queue<std::string, /* use default */, decltype(cmp_fn)> queue(cmp_fn);
```

**Note:** This is a simplified example of something more complicated I'm doing. Please don't answer with suggestion of the form: "just use `std::greater`". My question is about the template arguments.

Comment: Not directly, but a template alias would certainly seem viable, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
template <class T, class Comparator>
using dcpq = /*default container priority queue*/
    std::priority_queue<T, typename std::priority_queue<T>::container_type, Comparator>;
```

to be used like

```
int main() {
    auto cmp_fn = [](const std::string &left, const std::string &right)
                    { return right < left; };
    dcpq<std::string, decltype(cmp_fn)> queue(cmp_fn);
}
```

although directly writing

```
std::priority_queue<std::string, typename std::priority_queue<T>::container,
    decltype(cmp_fn)> queue(cmp_fn);
```

might be easier.

Comment: sorry but... what about using `std::priority_queue<T>::container_type` instead of `decltype(get_queue_storage(std::priority_queue<T>{}))`? I suppose you can do without `get_queue_storage()`

Comment: @max66 Yeah, that would be smarter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a specific solution for the second template parameter of `std::priority_queue`, I suppose you can use the `typename std::priority_queue<T>::container_type` in some way (see, by example, the solution from nwp; +1).

If your interested in a more general solution (non only for the second default template type, non only for `std::priority_queue`), I suppose you can first develop a type trait `type_n` to estract the n-th type from a list

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct type_n
 { using type = typename type_n<N-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct type_n<0U, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = T0; };
```

next a type traits `type_cnt_n` (that use `type_n`) to extract the n-th type argument of a template-template parameter

```
template <std::size_t, typename>
struct type_cnt_n;

template <std::size_t N, template <typename ...> class Cnt, typename ... Ts>
struct type_cnt_n<N, Cnt<Ts...>>
 { using type = typename type_n<N, Ts...>::type; };
```

and last (following the answer from nwp) a `make_priority_queue()` function

```
template <typename T, typename Cmp>
auto make_priority_queue (Cmp const & cmp)
 { return std::priority_queue<T,
      typename type_cnt_n<1U, std::priority_queue<T>>::type, Cmp> { cmp }; }
```

The problem of this solution is that works only with template-template types with type-only template parameter (so works with `std::priority_queue`, with `std::vector`, with `std::map` but doesn't work with `std::array`).

The following is a full working ... well, a full compiling... example

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct type_n
 { using type = typename type_n<N-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct type_n<0U, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t, typename>
struct type_cnt_n;

template <std::size_t N, template <typename ...> class Cnt, typename ... Ts>
struct type_cnt_n<N, Cnt<Ts...>>
 { using type = typename type_n<N, Ts...>::type; };


template <typename T, typename Cmp>
auto make_priority_queue (Cmp const & cmp)
 { return std::priority_queue<T,
      typename type_cnt_n<1U, std::priority_queue<T>>::type, Cmp> { cmp }; }

int main()
 {
   auto cmpFn = [](std::string const & l, std::string const &r)
    { return r < l; };

   auto pq = make_priority_queue<std::string>(cmpFn);
 }
```